# Регулярные выражения в URL

Tags: регулярные-выражения, url, пути

Добрый день, помогите пожалуйста.
Прописываю через регулярные выражения пути по урлам и заполняю метаданные на сайте.

страница любых продуктов выглядит так: `/products/MAHLE/OC195.html`
 путь -  `^\/products\/[\d\w\-\+]+\/[\d\w]+.html$`   . Работает

одна из странц каталог ТО вот так `/catalog/to/28/models/117.html`
`^\/catalog\/to\/\d+\/models/\d+\.html`   . Работает.

Абсолютно не могу добраться до страниц вида:

```
catalogs/motornye-masla/pav/4798.html?sort_type=cost_asc

/catalogs/akkumulyatornye-batarei/pav/8118.html?sort_type=cost_asc

/catalogs/akkumulyatornye-batarei/pav/38792/38874/8118/95616.html?sort_type=cost_asc
```

Количество числовых значей после `pav/` зависит от количества выбранных фильтров в каталоге.
Я был бы несоразмерно счастлив, если бы вы помогли указать путь к урлам, вида 
`/catalogs/akkumulyatornye-batarei/pav/8118.html?sort_type=cost_asc` , где числа после `pav` могут быть любыми, букв нет.

Пишу `^\/catalogs\/motornye-masla\/pav\/\d+\.html?sort_type=cost_asc` . Не работает(((

Если это вообще возможно пути к `/catalogs/akkumulyatornye-batarei/pav/38792/38874/8118/95616.html?sort_type=cost_asc`, то-есть `pav/`От 1 до 10 числовых значений(фильтров на сайте).`html?sort_type=cost_asc`

Заранее огромное спасибо!

Сайт http://partseasy.ru

Comment: Прошу прощения, пишу такой путь ^\/catalogs\/motornye-masla\/pav\/\d+\.html?sort_type=cost_asc  -   не работает

Comment: Так у вас перед `catalogs/motornye-masla` нет слеша ... Если он может быть, а может не быть, то должно быть `\/?catalogs/motornye-masla`. И "?" надо заэкранировать, иначе он воспринимается как квантор.

Comment: Я дико извниняюсь, вот путь, который у меня прописан ^\/catalogs\/motornye-masla\/pav\/\d+\.html?sort_type=cost_asc Можно привести хотя бы 1 пример? домен/каталогс/моторные масла/ это все со слешами всегда идет. Я не изучал выражения, а пути составлены "методом тыка" по открытой инфе в интернете и 1 шаблону готового выражения

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь огромное!! К сожалению пути не работают, вида \/catalogs\/motornye-masla\/pav\/[\/\d]+\.html\?sort_type=cost_asc и ^\/catalogs\/motornye-masla\/pav\/[\/\d]+\.html\?sort_type=cost_asc (((((

Comment: Так у вас действительно можнт не быть в начале пути слеша? Или это все же опечатка? Если опечатка, то должно работать, если нет, то после `^\/` поставьте `?`.

Comment: Смотрите,  я понимаю что из-за незнания праедмета, я Вас путаю. Я попробовал все 3 варианта: ^\/?catalogs\/motornye-masla\/pav\/[\/\d]+\.html\?sort_type=cost_asc  , ^\/catalogs\/motornye-masla\/pav\/[\/\d]+\.html\?sort_type=cost_asc   , \/?catalogs\/motornye-masla\/pav\/[\/\d]+\.html\?sort_type=cost_asc   Путь не указывается(( Вот страница к которой Вы пишите выражение http://partseasy.ru/catalogs/motornye-masla/pav/4798.html?sort_type=cost_asc

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/xV9f7d/1

Comment: Нет, такой путь не работает, я не знаю в чем дело(

Answer (score 0):

Для `/catalogs/motornye-masla/pav/4798.html?sort_type=cost_asc`:

```
\/catalogs\/motornye-masla\/pav\/[\/\d]+\.html\?sort_type=cost_asc
```

[Test](https://regex101.com/r/1a7ESW/1)

---

Для `/catalogs/akkumulyatornye-batarei/pav/8118.html?sort_type=cost_asc`, `/catalogs/akkumulyatornye-batarei/pav/38792/38874/8118/95616.html?sort_type=cost_asc`:

```
\/?catalogs\/akkumulyatornye-batarei\/pav\/[\/\d]+\.html\?sort_type=cost_asc
```

[Test](https://regex101.com/r/wXQ3st/1)

Comment: можно использовать # вместо / Тогда не нужно будет экранировать / внутри регулярки и читать будет значительно легче

Comment: Только эти пути не работают, к сожалению(

Comment: Есть какие-то альтернативы? В таком виде не работает

Comment: @MykolaVeriga, что это значит? Хэш и гет используются для разных целей, просто взять и заменить одно на другое ради того, что бы в регулярке не использовать экранирование - звучит как безумие.

Comment: @Станислав, какие альтернативы? Регулярки 100% рабочие, соответственно ошибка где-то ещё ... где именно - вне рамок задачи и понимания. Альтернативы наверняка есть, но нужны ли они - вопрос.

Comment: `preg_match('#/catalogs/motornye-masla/pav/[/\d]+\.html\?sort_type=cost_asc#', $str, $match);` вот что я имел ввиду удобнее читать когда не нужно екранировать каждый /

Comment: @MykolaVeriga, это не имеет никакого отоношения к классическому синтаксису регулярных выражений, тега "php" у вопроса нет. По этому это только вводит в заблуждение.

Comment: согласен, то что имел ввиду вынес в ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = '#/?catalogs/[\w-]+/pav/(?:[0-9]*/?)+(?:(?:\.html|htm|php)?\?sort_type=cost_(?:asc|desc))?#';
```

Сначала `/?`  / - это символ, ? - значит что он может быть, а может не быть.

`catalogs/` - это просто символы и они обезательно должны быть.

`[\w-]+` - любое название категории, может состоять с букв, цифр, нижнего подчеркивания и дефиса.

`/pav/` - просто символы.

`(?:[0-9]+/?)+` - групы вида 78987/

(?:) - група которая не будет запоминаться.

[0-9]+/? - набор цыфр от одной, с возможный ? вконце, потому что последняя група не будет иметь /

`(?:\.html|htm|php)?` - возможное наличие формата, его может и не быть

`\?`- символ ? перед гет параметрами

`sort_type=cost_(?:asc|desc)` - два варианта сорировки cost_asc и cost_desc

Comment: Этот путь тоже не работает, для аналогии, я приведу уже рабочие пути. ^\/$ - главная страница, ^\/catalog\/to\/\d+\/models/\d+\.html - каталог ТО домен//catalog/to/35/models/340.html, Каталог ТО ^\/catalog\/to\/\d+\/models/\d+\/types\/\d+\/products.html домен//catalog/to/35/models/340/types/22499/products.html

Comment: Возможно брак происходит, тому что вот эта часть урла "html?sort_type=cost_asc" появляется во всех каталогах после установки фильтра, я думаю, что эта часть указывается неверно. Хотя ничего в этом не понимаю, предыдущие пути методом научного тыка и информации из интернета.

Comment: тебе нужна одна регулярка которая будет проверять все или для каждого  урла отдельная?

Comment: поправил ответ, сделал необезательной последнюю часть

Comment: опиши более подробно что ты делаешь. То есть у тебя есть файл  там где много ссылок и тебе нужно отсеять нужные?